# How to render views count by browser in Sinatra and Datamapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have `View` and `Link` models

**Link**
has_many :views

**View**
belongs_to :link

```
irb(main):001:0> View.all
=> [#<View @id=1 @link_id=1 @browser="Chrome" @created_at=#<DateTime: 2013-04-23T21:21:23+02:00 ((2456406j,69683s,0n),+7200s,2
99161j)>>, #<View @id=2 @link_id=1 @browser="Firefox" @created_at=#<DateTime: 2013-04-23T21:21:26+02:00 ((2456406j,69686s,0n),+
200s,2299161j)>>]
```

How will be the best way to render table on `Link` show page with views count grouped by browser?

Comment: Just want to clarify: for a given `link_id`, you want to render a two-column table with "Browser" in one column and "Total views" in the other?

Comment: Yes, with browser name and views counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data you want by:

```
View.aggregate(:browser.count, :fields => [:browser], :conditions => ['link_id = ?', link_id])
```

Comment: Hmm, I got error: ``ArgumentError: condition :group does not map to a property or relationship in View`` I guess that is because I am using DataMapper

Comment: Oops, try :group => 'browser' instead?

Comment: there is now ``where`` method in Datamapper :)

Comment: Aw geez I was giving you ActiveRecord answers.  One sec, I'll fix it up to use Datamapper.

Comment: This should be something like: ``View.aggregate(:browser, :all.count)`` but how to check views only for specific link id?

Comment: Does `View.all(:conditions => {:link_id => link_id}).aggregrate(:browser, :all.count)` work?

Comment: Nope: ``NoMethodError: undefined method `aggregrate' for #<DataMapper::Collection:0x007fd6e35c8570>``

Comment: Next guess: `View.aggregate(:browser.count, :fields => [:browser], :conditions => ['link_id = ?', link_id])` .  Man, the docs for DataMapper kind of suck...

Comment: Awesome.  Glad I could help.  I've updated the answer to reflect our combined efforts.